# Connect to Sharepoint using Mac

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to use another editor instead of Sharepoint Designer and connect to the Sharepoint website through there? I am running on OSX. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint sites are accessible via WebDav, so any WebDav client can be used to connect and modify content. I'm a big fan of Coda for Mac (https://panic.com/coda/), but if you need to create or customize SharePoint Workflows, you'll still need to use SharePoint Designer.

UPDATE (4/9/20): I now use Visual Studio Code, with the SPGo plugin, though I still sometimes use Coda from my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you like to do. Some of the files can be accessed using the browser. For example Master Pages or Page Layouts: "Site Settings -> Master Pages and Page Layouts". You can download, modify and upload them again.

Comment: Aha, great. Is there a panel where I can find all the root files that are being used for the theme somewhere on the Sharepoint admin page? Or is it just master page and page layouts that are accessible?